# android universal type method

Tags: android, types, callback, android-asynctask

I've created a parent AsyncTask for other AsyncTasks to inherit off of. the Parent class implements a callback for the child classes to inherit. Looks something like this.

```
public abstract class BaseTask <Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask <Params, Progress, Result>{

    public interface AsyncTaskFinishedListener {
        public void onFinish(String returnItem);
    }

    protected AsyncTaskFinishedListener asyncTaskFinishedListener;

    public void setOnFinishedListener(AsyncTaskFinishedListener listener) {
        asyncTaskFinishedListener = listener;
    }    

}
```

Inherited classes call the `asyncTaskFinishedListener.onFinish(returnItem)` and a result from the async task is passed back to whatever class instantiated/executed the asynctask.  Is there a way for me to set the type of the item being called back (i.e. `returnitem` in onFinish) so that the class may be more diverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics like this

AsyncTaskFinishedListener.java:

```
public interface AsyncTaskFinishedListener<T> {
    public void onFinish(T returnItem);
}
```

BaseTask.java

```
public abstract class BaseTask <Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask <Params, Progress, Result>{



    protected AsyncTaskFinishedListener<Result> asyncTaskFinishedListener;

    public void setOnFinishedListener(AsyncTaskFinishedListener<Result> listener) {
        asyncTaskFinishedListener = listener;
    }    

}
```

usage:

```
public class SomeClass extends BaseTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>{
//.... abstract implementation goes here
}
new SomeClass().setOnFinishedListener(new AsyncTaskFinishedListener<Integer>(){
  @Override
  void onFinish(Integer result){
    //...do something with result
  }
});
```

**pros over Object+casting**: compile time error if you pass wrong type - with Object+casting you can get ClassCastException at runtime

Comment: I ended up just returning type `Object` instead and then casting the result to the desired type later on.  (there was another answer that suggested this and has removed since...).  Is there any benefit to using the generic type instead?